# ValueError: Labels not contained in axis?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, text-mining, lda

Complete beginner here!

I'm following a jupyter notebook tutorial on text mining via LDA:

http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/sekhansen/text-mining-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial_notebook.ipynb

In the tutorial, I have a .txt document with:

```
data.columns
Index(['president', 'speech', 'year'], dtype='object')
```

However, a few steps further, I try to switch the 'speech' column to the (estimated) topics found via LDA. This code is used in the tutorial:

```
data = data.drop('speech',1)
for i in range(ldaobj.K): data['T' + str(i)] = dt[:,i]
data.to_csv("final_output.csv",index=False)
```

(I switched `xrange()` to `range()` given that I'm using Python 3)

Now, when I run this, it gives me:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-45755ac70972> in <module>()
----> 1 data = data.drop('speech',1)
      2 for i in range(ldaobj.K): data['T' + str(i)] = dt[:,i]
      3 data.to_csv("final_output.csv",index=False)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in drop(self, 
labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   2528         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   2529             if labels is not None:
-> 2530                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, 
errors=errors)
   2531 
   2532         if inplace:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in 
_drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors)
   2560                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, 
errors=errors)
   2561             else:
-> 2562                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   2563             dropped = self.reindex(**{axis_name: new_axis})
   2564             try:

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in 
drop(self, labels, errors)
   3742             if errors != 'ignore':
   3743                 raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' 
%
-> 3744                                  labels[mask])
   3745             indexer = indexer[~mask]
   3746         return self.delete(indexer)

ValueError: labels ['speech'] not contained in axis
```

I was not sure if just the error was enough, so I posted everything just to be sure.

Do any of you know why this error pops up?